# Node.JS createServer without SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, server

I'm developping an intranet, to do so I'm using `Node.JS` without Express and until now I was using the `http module` with `createServer` but I noticed when I connect using localhost everything is fine, but when I connect to my server using the IP instead (from my machine or another device on the network) I get a warning in Chrome in the top-left corner saying that my site is not secured. I *think* this is because I'm using `http` instead of `https` but in order to use `https.createServer` I need to provide a SSL certificate, and I don't have one because I'm making an Intranet so it's not a website that need to be hella-secured since it will be deployed on a personal network only accessible from like 6 people.

I saw on tutorials that the options needs to look like :

```
options = {
    pfx: fs.readFileSync("ssl/crt.pfx"),
    passphrase: "password"
}
```

But I don't have any and I don't quite get how those work, I just want the message to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create HTTPS server without a SSL certificate, but you can use tools to do so, like OpenSSL, but the certificate will appear invalid.